# Show convergence of 1/cosh series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Sorry if my english is not correct. Feel free to edit and ask questions.

I need to test the following series on convergence:

a)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac { sinh(n) }{ e^n } $$
and

b)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac { 1 }{ cosh(n) } $$

we were told to solve b) by using the ratio test. But after ~5h of working on these examples we're pretty desperate.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) you do not need the ratio test: just note that $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sinh n} {\mathbb e ^n} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\mathbb e ^n - \mathbb e ^{-n}} {2 \mathbb e ^n} = \frac 1 2$. By the zero test, since the limit is not $0$ then the series diverges.

For (b) indeed, one could use the ratio test, but I shall use the root test: $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac 1 {\cosh n}} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] \frac 2 {\mathbb e ^n + \mathbb e ^{-n}} = \frac 1 {\mathbb e} \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt[n] 2} {\sqrt[n] {1+ \mathbb e ^{-2n}}} = \frac 1 {\mathbb e} < 1$, so the series is convergent. Alternatively, this could have been solved by using the comparison test (either with limit, or with inequalities) and comparing your series to $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty \frac 2 {\mathbb e ^n}$, which is convergent.

Comment: Lol thank you so much :-) we just got to 1/e < 1 by using the ratio test aswell *phew* while using the ratio test with question a) resulted in nothing. But ofc we the zero test is perfectly fine... I feel so f***ing stupid right now... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To do b) with the ratio test, consider that the ratio between terms is
$$\frac{\cosh n}{\cosh(n+1)} = \frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{n+1}+e^{-n-1}}\to e^{-1}<1$$
The hard part is rigorously showing the convergence but the idea is that the $e^{-n}$ terms become negligible as $n\to\infty$.
EDIT: This isn't hard. Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}=0,$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{e^{n+1}+e{-n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n}{e^{n+1}}$ provided that the second limit exists.

Because the ratio tends to a limit less than 1, you can find some $N$ such that before it the sum is finite and after it the sum converges by the ratio test

Answer (score 0):

For b) with ratio test:

$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{cosh(n)}{cosh(n+1)}} 
= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{e^k+e^{-k}}{e^{k+1}+e^{-k-1}}}
= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1+e^{-2k}}{e+e^{-2k-1}}} 
=\frac{1}{e}
$$